# django uwsgi and nginx = 400 bad request

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

I moved my Django website and pip3 install Django.
I use the same uswgi wrapper than on the install of server #1 and it works.
On server #2, I get a 400 Bad request.
If I stop the uwsgi server, I get a 502 bad gateway from NGINX and when UWSGI is started, it receives my requests as I refresh the page.

Still, the website doesn't show, only 400 bad request page from uWSGI/Django as it appear.

Can anyone help me out on that ? I don't have much knowledge of Django, am just a sole sysadmin and need to load balance that Django website.*

Here's a pastebin of the output when I run the UWSGI server: pastebin.com/raw/JwssyZst

Please help!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I added the hostname of my new server to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py and local_settings.py